# Add simple keybinding in Atom

Tags: shell, key-bindings, atom-editor

How can I add a keybinding in Atom to run rustfmt on the current file? Do I have to create or install a package?  Can I attach it to the "Editor: Auto Indent" command?  How do I find out which package Auto Indent comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package called [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) which [seems to have preliminary support for rustfmt](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/358).